# Grouped UITableView - remove 'Prototype Cells' header in interface builder

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder

I have a UITableView placed on my view controller in IB, using 2 prototype cells and 'Grouped' style.  There will only ever be 2 cells in the table, and no group header so I want to resize the height of the table view control to be just tall enough to accomodate the 2 rows (each of height 29) so I have room for my other controls on the VC.  Problem is, when I resize the height of the table in IB, it always shrinks at the bottom and retains the 'Prototype Cells' label.  This means to get the right height and position I have to lose visibility of my cell designs - see screenshot :

[image]

Is there anyway to turn off the 'Prototype Cells' group header label so I can resize my controls WYSIWYG style?

Answer (score 0):

It will be more useful to show your code and what `UITableView` delegate methods you have implemented in your VC. Anyways, try this : set your header `@property` for the tableView to nil and if you get no result implement this:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return nil;
}
```

Hope this will work. Cheers

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply however I think you misunderstood.  I'm not referring to any behaviour at run-time, I'm just talking about designing the view controller using interface builder.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to change the uitableview to static in stead of dynamic cells. This allows you to add the cells in the layout editor. You can then make iboutlets to the cells and there content. The downside of this is that you will have to use a UITableViewController as root which in turn doesn't let you add anything else then cells, headers and footers.

You can still add the rest of your components in a separate sections and just set the cell to background to invisible. or you could load the controller grab the view and resize it and add it to another viewcontrollers view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  Unfortunately I need other controls on my view controller so I can't use UITableViewController.